# How can I use Entity Framework .SqlQuery so that it can by multiple clients at once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have a method that has a loop that executes a stored procedure. The number of items to loop through can be 10,000 or more. This all works fine when one client is trying to run the report at a time, however when multiple clients try to run the report, it locks up all clients and errors out. The error created is:

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

The error is generated on the line where I try to use "results" The endpoint then remains locked up for all users until the application is restarted. I have never experienced this issue before, this is also the first time I have used Entity Framework to generate a large report before. How can I avoid this error? Here is the code:

```
foreach (var item in upcList)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item[0]))
        {
            string upc;

            if (DropCheckDigit != true)
            {
                upc = Helpers.upc.formatBRDUpc(item[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                upc = Helpers.upc.formatBRDUpcDropCheckDigit(item[0]);
            }

            var results = BRDataDb.Database.SqlQuery<ProductMovementItem>("EXEC MoC_MoCHub_GetItemData @p0, @p1", upc, DataSource).FirstOrDefault();

            if (results != null)
            {
                if (results.BaseQty != 0 && results.BasePrice != 0)
                {
                    results.Margin = (((results.BasePrice / results.BaseQty) - results.cost) / (results.BasePrice / results.BaseQty)) * 100;

                    if (results.Margin != null)
                    {
                        results.Margin = decimal.Round(decimal.Parse(results.Margin.ToString()), 2);
                    }
                }

                PMIList.Add(results);
                progressCounter += 1;
                Helpers.SharedFunctions.SendProgress("Processing...", progressCounter, (upcList.Count * 2), connectionId);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where / how is `BRDataDb` defined? Does each request get it's own instance?

Comment: BRDataDB is defined as: private static BRDataContext BRDataDb = new BRDataContext(); how can I create a new instance for each request?

Comment: You can `new` it in the controllers constructor, and perhaps later on look at dependency injection.  But if this is static, then that is likely the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try dispose

```
foreach (var item in upcList)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item[0]))
            {
                string upc;

                if (DropCheckDigit != true)
                {
                    upc = Helpers.upc.formatBRDUpc(item[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    upc = Helpers.upc.formatBRDUpcDropCheckDigit(item[0]);
                }

                using (BRDataDb db = new BRDataDb())
                {
                    var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProductMovementItem>("EXEC MoC_MoCHub_GetItemData @p0, @p1", upc, DataSource).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (results != null)
                    {
                        if (results.BaseQty != 0 && results.BasePrice != 0)
                        {
                            results.Margin = (((results.BasePrice / results.BaseQty) - results.cost) / (results.BasePrice / results.BaseQty)) * 100;

                            if (results.Margin != null)
                            {
                                results.Margin = decimal.Round(decimal.Parse(results.Margin.ToString()), 2);
                            }
                        }

                        PMIList.Add(results);
                        progressCounter += 1;
                        Helpers.SharedFunctions.SendProgress("Processing...", progressCounter, (upcList.Count * 2), connectionId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think disposing is indeed what's lacking. It's better though to just state this as an answer, not as a question (in general, answers shouldn't need response from the one who posted the question. Stack Overflow is not a forum). Also try to explain why it is different.

Comment: Dispose will only mask the problem since there is only ever one object in memory.  Depending how long the large query takes, multiple people could still see the error.  Also dbcontexts are not thread safe so you shouldn't be sharing one across your app, but creating an instance as needed.

Comment: @Fran I agree with you. can be a solution like unitofwork, also static objects may cause